# VS 2010 - How to fix in creating Visual Studio 2010 Project Themes folders inside the solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Whenever I open a file (ex. aspx, ascx) or a solution using VS, it creates the following 3 folders next to a file or a solution.

- Visual Studio 2010
- Visual Studio 2010Projects
- visual studio 2010Templates

Recently, there has been a problem with Windows User Account in our network; the profile issue has been fixed by Network Admin.

I'm wondering how to fix that VS issue. Thanks in advanced.

[image]

Comment: The issue is Automatically creating 3 folders. I think it should be using setting side Documents/Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the ***Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/General*** dialog, and make sure the settings are correct for *Projects Location*, *User Projects Template Location*, and *User Items Template Location.*

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I added the screenshot. Is it the setting how supposed to look like?

Comment: Hmm, well mine looks like `c:\Documents and Settings\My Name\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects` ...etc.